# how to show virtual column with calculated runtime values(i.e not in database) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've following table **stuinfo**

```
+------------+-------+-----------+
|   Roll_no  | Name  | Lastname  |
+------------+-------+-----------+
|   37032    | johny | bravo     |
|   37034    |  sam  | smith     |
+------------+-------+-----------+
```

and second one **stu_attendace**

```
+------------+-------+-----------+
|   Roll_no  | Name  | month     |
+------------+-------+-----------+
|   -1       | total |   26      |
|   37032    | johny |   19      |
|   37034    |  sam  |   25      |
+------------+-------+-----------+
```

Total days are 26 , so johny's attendance is 73.03% and  Sam's attendance is 95.03% .

So how can I show their Attendance with percentage by calculating at run-time and showing those values in new column 'per_attendace' which is actually not in database. like shown in below

```
+----------+--------+-----------+---------------+
|  roll_no |  name  | last_name | per_attendace |
+----------+--------+-----------+---------------+
|  37032   |  johny | bravo     |  xx %         |
|  37034   |  sam   | smith     |  xx %         |
+----------+--------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Could you share what you've tried thus far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do what you want, in the `SELECT` clause you can select a literal value, or a column name, or any valid expression.

Just `JOIN` the two tables, and then calculate the percent like this:

```
SELECT 
  i.roll_no,
  i.name,
  i.Lastname,
  ((a.month / 26) * 100) AS percent
FROM stuinfo AS i
INNER JOIN stu_attendance AS a ON i.Roll_no = a.Roll_no;
```

**Note that:**

- There is no need to duplicate the column name in both the two tables, just remove it from the other table, and keep your tables [***normalized***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).
- Don't store the total value like this as a value in the column.

---

**Update:**

If you want to select the value of the total from the database, you can do this:

```
SELECT 
  i.roll_no,
  i.name,
  i.Lastname,
  ((a.month / (SELECT month 
               FROM stu_attendace
               WHERE name = 'total')) * 100) AS percent
FROM stuinfo AS i
INNER JOIN stu_attendance AS a ON i.Roll_no = a.Roll_no;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](https://www.google.com.eg/#btnK=%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%AB+Google%E2%80%8F&q=mysql+round+number)

---

You can also set that total value as a variable instead of the correlated subquery, like this:

```
SET @total = 0;

SELECT month 
FROM stu_attendace
WHERE name = 'total'
INTO @total;
```

Then:

```
SELECT 
  i.roll_no,
  i.name,
  i.Lastname,
  ROUND(((a.month / @total) * 100), 2) AS percent
FROM stuinfo AS i
INNER JOIN stu_attendace AS a ON i.Roll_no = a.Roll_no;
```

I used the `ROUND` function to round the number to only two decimal values.

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e4e7/7)

Comment: ya 26 is like auto increment for total month attendance, is there any other way to store that ?

Comment: @RnzTx - What do you mean by auto increment for total month attendance, please explain the scenario for that.

Comment: mins when i add new attendance for subject then then total attendance is automatically get incremented but i don't know where to store that exctly so.. i did that itselt in total of student attendance

Comment: @RnzTx - So you have another table for `subject` right? If so why not store it as  a column for the subject table if so.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal sorry i didn't get u.. !

Comment: @RnzTx - I mean is there another table that you use to store details about the subject?

Comment: @MahmoudGama No.. Table1 stores the info about each attendance & table2 stores total number of attendance taken and total number of attendance for each student.

Comment: @RnzTx - I didn't fully understand your scenario, but I can suggest that you create another table called `AttendenceInfo` with columns `Total`, `month` put the total in it.

Comment: @RnzTx - Feel free to ask me again if something goes wrong, or you have any further problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select a.roll_no , a.name ,a.last_name,(b.month/26)*100 as  per_attendace 
from stuinfo as a join 
stu_attendace as b on a.roll_no=b.roll_no
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT i.roll_no, i.name, i.Lastname, ((a.month / 26) * 100) AS percent
  FROM stuinfo AS i
 INNER JOIN stu_attendance AS a ON i.Roll_no = a.Roll_no;
```